# ANT: Starting a background process on windows

Tags: ant

I want ANT to execute a .cmd file on windows machine... but the command prompt should not be displayed. the process should be running in background. Ant should just fire the command and proceed with the next command. 
I even tried using the windows "/B" switch, but it did not work. 
Does anybody have a suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

Use exec task like that :

```
 <exec executable="cmd" spawn="true">
   <arg value="/c"/>
   <arg value="foobar.cmd"/>
 </exec>
```

That should be sufficient, otherwise if you need to use start /B ... :

```
 <exec executable="cmd">
   <arg value="/c"/>
   <arg value="start"/>
   <arg value="/b">
   <arg value="foobar.cmd"/>
 </exec>
```

See [ant manual exec task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html) for details.

Comment: The start command has a "/min" option for running the command minimised (without a console to bother users). See http://www.computerhope.com/starthlp.htm

Comment: Using the 1st option cmd got executed but after that control doesnt come back to execute rest of the commands in the ant build.xml file. I am starting application server in the exec task, so i want the after starting the servers in background, rest of the operations should be performed normally.

Comment: when your cmd called from exec has finished, Ant should get the control again. Look in your taskmanager, whether the external process opened by exec task gets closed correctly. To make sure that process gets closed in any case, use <parallel threadCount="1" timeout="timeout in milliseconds">..your exec goes here ...</parallel> see http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/parallel.html
Also try to start your cmd standalone to see if it works correctly outside from ant.

Comment: @Rebse: when i execute the command manually from command prompt, it executes successfully but even at that time i dont get the command prompt back after executing is completed. when i use ant, the same thing happens... ant gets stuck after executing the command. rest of the statements are not executed. the prob is that i DONT WANT THE EXTERNAL PROCESS TO END... i want is to be started in background

Comment: see my edit, use exec task with attribute spawn="true" (default = false)